# Getting installation error on working package when using apt

Tags: apt, package-management

I've installed a package called `leap` for Leap Motion sensor. The software, drivers, etc, works perfectly fine. Whenever I run subsequent `apt-*` operations unrelated to `leap` I get the following errors:

```
Setting up leap (2.3.1+31549) ...
Leap Motion installed under /usr/bin and /usr/sbin
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/init.d/leapd’: File exists
dpkg: error processing package leap (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 leap
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm using 15.10. Is there a way I can use the error message to manually do whatever it's trying to do so that the error is suppressed? Thanks!

Comment: Try to add `-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"` in your `apt` command

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also, so I try above things and solved.

```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove leap
```

and download hot fix version

https://leapmotion.app.box.com/s/rlwzvt680i5r6zes75ge36ub2yt7ksx3

(from https://community.leapmotion.com/t/linux-support-situation/4523)

I downloaded bottom one

and just install Leap-2.3.1+33747-x64.deb